# Can't create an object of type interface with data collected from ngrx store

Tags: angular, typescript, object, interface, ngrx

I have this interface:

```
export interface AuthStateInterface {
    isSubmitting: boolean,
    X_HI_CODE: string,
    token: string,
    userId : number,
    roleId: number   
}
```

And I want to create an object of this interface type with some data collected from the ngrx store within another class with the method initializeValues() that creates the objects as bellow:

```
  initializeValues(): void {
    const data: AuthStateInterface = {
      isSubmitting: false,
      X_HI_CODE: this.store.pipe(select(xhicodeSelector)),
      token: this.store.pipe(select(tokenSelector)),
      userId : this.store.pipe(select(userIdSelector)),
      roleId: this.store.pipe(select( roleIdSelector)),
    };
    console.log('data', data)
  }
```

But Visual Studio errors out as you can see on the screenshot bellow:
[image]

When I hover on the red alert, this is what it says:

[image]

I will be greatfull if anyone can help me fix this.

Comment: Ngrx selectors return Observables. In order to make this work, you can use combineLatest with all selectors inside and in the subscribe create this object.

Comment: combineLatest will combine all 5 five properties of the interface, but how can the object be created with the name data, because I want to pass the data as an argument to another function for api call.

Comment: Even better if you can want to use it combined with a http call as that is also an observable. So you can do something like combineLatest(… obs..).pipe(switchMap( data => http.post).subscribe ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several concepts of angular or typescript in general that I was misunderstanding. As @MikeOne said in the comments, Ngrx selectors return Observables, and I had to subscribe and assign them to the variables I've declared previously. So this is what I did:

1- I initialized the variables, not observables:

```
isSubmitting!: boolean
  token!: string
  roleId!: [number]
  userId!: string
```

2- I selected the data from the ngrx-store with the selector hook

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeValues()
    this.getAllStaff()
  }
  
  initializeValues(): void {

    this.store
    .pipe(select(isSubmittingSelector), map((isSubmitting) => isSubmitting))
    .subscribe(value => this.isSubmitting = value);
    this.store

    .pipe(select(tokenSelector), map((token) => token))
    .subscribe(value => this.token = value);

    this.store
    .pipe(select(roleIdSelector), map((roleId) => roleId))
    .subscribe(value => this.roleId = value);

    this.store
    .pipe(select(userIdSelector), map((userId) => userId))
    .subscribe(value => this.userId = value);
  }
```

3- Then I used the values to create the data passed to next promise

```
   getAllPersnlValues() {
    const data: AuthStateInterface = {
      isSubmitting: this.isSubmitting,
      X_HI_CODE: this.HI_CODE,
      token: this.token,
      userId : this.userId,
      roleIds: this.roleId,
    };
    console.log('data', data);
   
    return this.persnlService.getPersnl(data)
    .pipe(
      map((response) => response)
    );
  }
```

There should be a shorter way to do it, and with my Reactjs background I had much more to learn about rxjs before boasting on simpler technics. But this approach made this task completed.